# How does GCC link objects?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I can link my example.o using this command with no problem

```
gcc example.o -o example.exe
```

but if I manually link it using `ld`, I get many errors:

```
ld example.o -o example.exe
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1d7e5): undefined reference to `strcmp'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1d9b6): undefined reference to `_ftime'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1dcbd): undefined reference to `strchr'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1df7f): undefined reference to `strtoul'
...
```

How does `gcc` invoke the linker and link the object file into an executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is more complex than you imagine.

Run

```
gcc -v example.o -o example.exe
```

to understand what is happening

The gory details are operating system specific. On Linux, it silently loads `crt*.o`  objects (containing the `_start` assembly code calling your `main` etc etc...) and the C library. I have no idea of what your platform is doing; I never compiled on Windows.

Comment: thankyou very much. i can see gcc is doing some complex thing in the background during linking. thanks again for the answer :)

Comment: by the way, how do i link a simple helloworld.o object to an executable using ld?

Comment: You don't, you use `gcc` for linking `helloworld`. Otherwise, you won't ask!!! (And the answer is utterly system dependent, since you have to reproduce what `gcc -v` shows you).